# Virtual hosts subdomains pointing to wrong directory

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I created 2 virtual hosts http:// web1.com:2107 pointing to "/var/www/web1" folder and second http:// web2.com:2107 pointing to "/var/www/web2". all subdomains in web2 are working fine, But in case of web1.com:2107 i am able to see only home page. when i try to open any subdomain from web1 like http:// games.web1.com:2107 it points to web2's home page ie /var/www/web2/ directory

Is there anything wrong in configuration ?

below is the code for hosts i am using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  web2.com
ServerAdmin myeow@web2.com
ServerAlias http://www.web2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/web2
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/web2>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog    /var/www/web2/error80.log
CustomLog   /var/www/web2/access80.log Combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:2107>
ServerName  web2.com    
ServerAdmin myeow@web2.com
ServerAlias http://www.web2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/web2
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/web2>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/web2/error.log
CustomLog   /var/www/web2/access80.log Combined
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/web2.com_access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

===================================================================

```
NameVirtualHost *:2107
<VirtualHost *:2107>
    ServerName web1.com
    ServerAlias http://web1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/web1
    <Directory /var/www/web1/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog        /var/www/web1/error.log
    CustomLog       /var/www/web1/access.log Combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I had the same and in my case part with "NameVirtualHost *:80" was i a file that was not included in main httpd.conf - so vhosts were not enabled at all, and therefor all pointing into default vhost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have several VirtualHosts one of them is the default VirtualHost.
It's the first one in alphabetic order of the file containing the definition of the VirtualHost.

When you remove a VirtualHost. If you still have an entry in the Hosts file or a DNS record, when the query is performed on your Apache server, if it cannot find the right VirtualHost (ServerName or ServerAlias), then the default one is taken to process the answer.

When you add a new VirtualHost, if you make a mistake in the ServerName or ServerAlias you'll also have the default VH.

*Update*

Now that the question is complete I can see you are not using ServerAlias in the right way. All your subdomains should be listed in ServerAlias directives, without the http://
So you should have:

```
ServerName web1.com
ServerAlias www.web1.com
ServerAlias games.web1.com
```

You could maybe try a *.web1.com.
Else when you use a name which is not listed the default vhost is used (and here vhost web2.com is defined before so it's the default one on this port)

Comment: There are less chances og making mistake i have as much as less code for new VH, Below is the code 
NameVirtualHost *:2107
<VirtualHost *:2107>
    ServerName tab.com
    ServerAlias http://tab.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tab3
    <Directory /var/www/tab3/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: AllowOverrid All means you can have .htaccess files adding things to your conf. Put None instead, and remove Multiviews

Comment: I made the changes, but still getting same problem...when i open subdomains it points to wrong directory :( is there anything i am missing ??

Comment: add different AccessLog directives in your VH and check the one which is really hit. Run `Apache2 -S` to list available VH, etc. And edit your questions with code from both VH, not just one.

Comment: I just tried adding different access log for both the VH, when i open web1 it logs in web1's log file, web2 is logging in web2's access log. there is no mixing

Comment: .. So maybe make a clear explanation of your problem. In apache side you have two VH. works well. Make a clear test case. complete . so that we could find something strange inside. Maybe you forgot the port in your link.

Comment: Sorry if i have confused u :( ok let me explain again. There are 2 VH. Home page and all subdomains from www.web2.com:2107 are working fine. but when i open http://web1.com:2107 only this time it points to correct directory...whn i try to call any subdomain like http://games.web1.com it points to root directory of http://www.web1.com:2107

Comment: @Amit Patil: you are trying to be an example of bad-way-of-asking-a-question :-) . Stop commenting. Edit your question and put inside a clear explanation of your problems. Maybe by just trying to explain yourself what is the situation you'll find an answer by your own. But if you do not do this step no one will find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After you change an Apache Conf, you have to restart the service. Not sure if that was the problem, but it never hurts to check ;)

Comment: Yeh, i forgot to mention it but i restarted the service 2-3 times

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I couldnt be of more help then, glad you got it working though :P

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the problem half, there was entry left behind in HOSTS file so that page was still available with deleted host name entry. Now the half problem still there. now i created one more host entry and pointed to diff location but still its pointing to old location :(

Answer (score 0):

For Cloudflare users wich have some issues with SSL and a wrong directory:

Change the SSL Mode at Crypto from `Flexible` to `Full`.

This helped me.

Comment: Full Strict or just only full?